# Filling an empty multi-dimensional matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am parsing data from a fasta file into a dictionary, then looping through the value's to get the hamming distance for each sequence and I am having a hard time filling an empty multi-dimensional array with the output of the hamming distance function.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from scipy.spatial import distance
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import manifold
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

seq_dict = {rec.id : rec.seq for rec in SeqIO.parse("HW2.fas", "fasta")} #parsing fasta file into dic
ham_matrix = np.empty((0, 0 ), int)

for x in seq_dict.values():
    for y in seq_dict.values():
        distance.hamming(x, y)
    ham_matrix = np.append(ham_matrix, np.array([distance.hamming(x, y)]))

print (ham_matrix)
```

The matrix once printed out should have the dimensions of 120 rows and 120 columns (the length of the dictionary) but instead the output is

```
[0.29924242 0.3030303  0.3030303  0.30681818 0.30681818 0.29924242
 0.3030303  0.29924242 0.3030303  0.3030303  0.3030303  0.30681818
 0.3030303  0.3030303  0.3030303  0.29924242 0.32575758 0.32954545
 0.32575758 0.32575758 0.32954545 0.32954545 0.32575758 0.32954545
 0.32575758 0.32954545 0.33333333 0.32575758 0.32575758 0.3219697
 0.3219697  0.32575758 0.32954545 0.32954545 0.32954545 0.32954545
 0.32575758 0.32954545 0.32575758 0.3219697  0.31818182 0.32954545
 0.17424242 0.17424242 0.17045455 0.17045455 0.17424242 0.17045455
 0.17424242 0.1780303  0.17424242 0.17424242 0.17045455 0.17424242
 0.16666667 0.17045455 0.17045455 0.1780303  0.1780303  0.17424242
 0.17424242 0.17424242 0.18560606 0.18181818 0.18560606 0.18939394
 0.19318182 0.18939394 0.17424242 0.18181818 0.18181818 0.1780303
 0.18560606 0.1969697  0.17045455 0.18939394 0.1780303  0.18939394
 0.18560606 0.19318182 0.1780303  0.11742424 0.11363636 0.11742424
 0.11742424 0.08712121 0.10984848 0.10606061 0.10227273 0.08712121
 0.11742424 0.10984848 0.08712121 0.08333333 0.10984848 0.09090909
 0.09848485 0.10984848 0.07954545 0.10606061 0.08712121 0.10227273
 0.11363636 0.10227273 0.09090909 0.00757576 0.10227273 0.10606061
 0.10227273 0.10606061 0.00757576 0.09848485 0.09090909 0.00378788
 0.10984848 0.07954545 0.09469697 0.10606061 0.10606061 0.        ]
```

Would it be better to just create an empty array, fill that empty array with the output from the hamming distance function, and THEN append that array as a row into the empty matrix after every loop?

Comment: "I am having a hard time" - please describe more in detail what is the problem

Comment: thank you, the matrix should be a 120 rows by 120 columns(length of dictionary) but I have edited the post to show the output I am currently getting.

Comment: Don't try to imitate the list append loop with `np.append`.  It is slower and harder to get right.

Answer (score 0):

#### First:

You should assign the value that `distance.hamming(x, y)` returns to some variable. Otherwise You will compute it in vain, and later in the array assignment do it again.

#### Second:

Your array assignment is quite circumstancial, and also in the wron place, I think.

Try this:

```
for i, x in enumerate(seq_dict.values()):
    for j, y in enumerate(seq_dict.values()):
        ham_matrix[i, j] = distance.hamming(x, y)
```

Untested code. Please comment below if that doesn't solve it.

By the way: The random-seeming values in your matrix are because You use the `np.empty()` function. It just allocates the memory it will need for the array and keeps the values that the computer saved there before. If You use `np.zeros()`, it will be filled with zeros, which usually clears things up. :)

Comment: That actually helped a ton! Thank you! The only issue left is that I am getting a IndexError: too many indices for array, which I am assuming is due to distance.hamming(x,y) only being 1 dimensional.

Comment: Ah, I see. No, I'm pretty sure that is due to your initializing `ham_matrix` with dimensions `(0, 0)`. Use the output dimensions You want there, `(120, 120)`. The output of `distance.hamming()` is a float, as you can find out [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.hamming.html#scipy.spatial.distance.hamming) :)

Comment: It works!! I really appreciate the help! Sorry for my code having a lot of mistakes, this is the first course where I am using Python and its a bit different from Java.